# Not able to execute build.xml from my Mac terminal. It gives -bash: ant: command not found

Tags: bash, ant

Not able to execute build.xml from my Mac terminal. It gives -bash: ant: command not found . I am trying to give this command from the directory where my build.xml is there. But still it is giving me the error. But good thing is that, I am able to execute it from my eclipse.

Tried executing 
source setAppPath.sh
. setAppPath.sh

But it is not recognizing PATH too.

This is what I have in my .bash_profile.

export KAPSEL_HOME=/Users/Bindu/SAP/MobileSDK3/KapselSDK # Apache Ant export ANT_HOME = /Users/Bindu/apache-ant-1.10.1 # Export to PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:$KAPSELHOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin –

Comment: when executing echo $PATH it is showing /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/bin:/bin:/bin

Answer (score 0):

Your missing ant's bin directory from your path, which makes me think you're also missing ANT_HOME.

You need to go to your home directory end edit your .bash_profile file, make sure you add this after everything that's already in there.

`ANT_HOME=/directory_where_ant_is_installed/actual_ant_directory
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin
export ANT_HOME PATH`

Comment: This is what I have in my bash profile.                        export KAPSEL_HOME=/Users/Bindu/SAP/MobileSDK3/KapselSDK
# Apache Ant
export ANT_HOME = /Users/Bindu/apache-ant-1.10.1
# Export to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$KAPSELHOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin

Comment: Are the spaces present in the file too? You can add this as an edit to your question to make it more clear. Also, is it ".bash_profile" or "bash_profile"?

Comment: just edited in my question. yes, there are spaces as displayed. And it is .bash_profile